# ¿Es posible utilizar un fragmento de bootstrap sin necesidad de importar la totalidad?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, angular

tengo una duda específica con respecto al uso de `bootstrap`. Resulta que deseo desarrollar una aplicación en la que necesito implementar un modal, y no deseo importar completamente la librería para no tener interferencia en el sistema donde tengo que insertar dicha aplicación. No puedo utilizar `ng-bootstrap` por cuestiones de conflicto con el otro sistema, es por ello que utilizo `bootstrap` convencional.
Con respecto a las clases `css` de `bootstrap` para el modal no tengo ningún inconveniente ya que solo copio y pego en una hoja de estilos las clases que necesito y las renombro en caso de ser necesario. 
Mi duda específica es saber como proceder (si es que es posible) con las líneas de código `javascript` de `bootstrap` correspondientes al modal. 
Revisando la documentación de `bootstrap` se puede encontrar el código `javascript` correspondiente a cada componente, ya sea un carousel o un modal, como se puede observar en el siguiente link:

[Enlace ficheros bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/js/dist)

Suponiendo que tengo una copia de los ficheros javascript necesarios para el funcionamiento del modal, de que manera puedo llamarlos y vincularlos en Angular?

Para ejemplificar lo que estoy intentado hacer, dejo un enlace de stackblitz con una simplificación de lo que pretendo implementar:

[Enlace Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qm7enk)

En dicho enlace, el proyecto es muy sencillo. Se trata de un componente denominado popup que consta de un botón que al presionarlo debe desplegar un modal con un campo de texto. Cuando el usuario introduce un valor, este se despliega en pantalla. A continuación muestro la sucesión de eventos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para mostrar este funcionamiento (temporal) usé el cdn de `bootstrap.min.js` en el fichero `index.html`. Lo he desactivado, porque justamente no puedo usar la totalidad de la librería por conflicto con el otro sistema.

Es posible lo que estoy intentado hacer? Aclaro que soy nuevo en todo lo que respecta al desarrollo web y probablemente estoy pasando por alto varias cosas.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer para solo utilizar los estilos que necesitas, es instalar bootstrap por medio de npm y solo importar los componentes que son necesarios:

1. Installa bootstrap por medio de npm

```
npm install bootstrap
```

> Es probable que tengas que installar jquery si es que no lo tienes ya.

2. Crea un archivo `custom-bootstrap.scss` dentro de tu carpeta `src/` con el siguiente contenido

```
// src/custom-bootstrap.scss
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "bootstrap/scss/modal"; // importa solo los estilos del modal
```

3. En tu archivo `src/main.ts` importa el archivo anterior, asi como el script para que los modals funcionen.

```
import './polyfills';
import './custom-bootstrap.scss';
import 'bootstrap/js/src/modal.js'; //importa solo el script del modal

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
...
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha funcionado. Saludos.